# replacing the 1st to nth match of the string. javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, pattern-matching

The problem is I want to replace a certain string on its `1st` occurence up to the `nth`  occurence. where `n` can be any number.

sample test string:

```
// 'one-two' the string I want to search
var str = "73ghone-twom2j2hone-two2717daone-two213";
```

I need to replace the first `"one-two"` up to the nth match with `"one"`.

```
//so in terms of function. i need something like:
function replaceByOccurence(testSring, regex, nthOccurence) {
    //implementation here
}
```

Given the function above, if I pass `3` as `nthOccurence`, it should replace the first match up to the 3rd match. if I pass `2` as `nthOccurence`, it should replace the first match up to the 2nd match, so in our example, if we pass `2`, it should return `"73ghonem2j2hone2717daone-two213"`. notice that the third `"one-two"` doesn't get replaced to `"one"`.

Can anyone help?
I searched but I cannot find a similar problem here.

---

**Mini Update** [SOLVED: check the last update]

So I used the first solution of @anubhava, and tried to put it in String as function. 
I wrote it this way:

```
String.prototype.replaceByOccurence = function(regex, replacement, nthOccurence) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nthOccurence; i++)
        this = this.replace(regex, replacement);
    return this;
};

//usage
"testtesttest".replaceByOccurence(/t/, '1', 2);
```

apparently I am getting a reference error. It said that the `left side assignment is not a reference` and it is pointing to `this = this.replace(regex, replacement)`.

---

**Last Update**

I changed the code to this:

```
String.prototype.replaceByOccurence = function (regex, replacement, nthOccurence) {
    if (nthOccurence > 0)
        return this.replace(regex, replacement)
        .replaceByOccurence(regex, replacement, --nthOccurence);

    return this;
};
```

and it is now working.

Comment: What is your expected output after first match up to the 3rd match of `one-two`?

Comment: @anubhava expected output is: `"73ghonem2j2hone2717daone213"` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simple loop can do the job:

```
function replaceByOccurence(input, regex, replacement, nthOccurence) {
    for (i=0; i<nthOccurence; i++)
       input = input.replace(regex, replacement);
    return input;
}
```

And call it as:

```
var replaced = replaceByOccurence(str, /one-two/, 'one', 3);
```

**EDIT:** Another version **without looping**

```
function replaceByOccurence(input, regex, replacement, num) {
    i=0;
    return input.replace(regex, function($0) { return (i++<num)? replacement:$0; });
}
```

And call it as:

```
var replaced = replaceByOccurence(str, /one-two/g, 'one', 3);
//=> 73ghtwom2j2htwo2717datwo213
```

Comment: wow. thanks for this. is there any way to do this with just regex?

Comment: Not sure if a single regex can do this in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var myregex = /(.*?one-two){3}(.*)/;
result = yourString.replace(myregex, function(match) {
  return  match(1).replace(/one-two/g, "one") + match(2);
});
```

- The match is the whole string
- match(1) is the beginning of the string up to the third `one-two`
- match(2) is the rest of the string
- we replace the string with a transformed match(1) (where we have replaced `one-two` with `one`) plus the rest of the string